# Detect if an SSD is failing/reaching its end of life and its write count in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, ssd

One of the laptops in my care is equipped with 256GB SSD as a main drive. The usual use is many quick-and-dirty bash scripts to pre-process data, meaning that the drive is being fairly frequently written to and re-written.

Recently, the system seems to be slower and it also seems that disk space is being lost.

Is there any simple way to diagnose the drive and tell if it is reaching its maximum of rewrites?

Comment: I would use one of the many ssd tools that exist on OS X operating system to check this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It the total drive space is being reduced that very likely means that blocks are being marked as bad by the disks controller.

The good news is that SSD’s only generally fail on write. The controller will read what it has written, realize it wasn’t able to flip one of the bits and mark it is bad and move that block to another physical address on the disk.

The bad news is that will slow down your system while it is performing these copies.

So you can just keep using it until is all burned up. Or go with a different type of drive, or make a RAM disk to do this type of repeated writing to, and save your expensive SSD drive.